# Resize TableLayoutPanel when adjacent control is resized

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

A WinForms application. One of the forms consists of a `MenuStrip`, a custom control `LabelProgressBar` below that, and a `TableLayoutPanel` below that.

While the program is running, the size of the `LabelProgressBar` is changed. The `TableLayoutPanel` should expand or contract as it is resized. So, if the height of the `LabelProgressBar` is reduced to zero, it should look as if the `TableLayoutPanel` and its contents are directly below the `MenuStrip`.

[image]

A screenshot can be included if it would be helpful.

So, far attempts have been made with various dock and anchor arrangements for the appropriate controls, and none resulted in the required behaviour.

Comment: Why not put them both in a `SplitContainer`?

Comment: @gnud yes, I am just trying that right now. Would the key be to resize the `SplitContainer` on the resize event of the custom progress bar control?

Comment: Actually, this was a lot harder to do than I thought with the `SplitContainer`, but works perfectly with two normal panels, one docked to the top, and one docked to `Fill`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly with two panels - one for the top, with `DockStyle.Top`, and the "main" one with `DockStyle.Fill`.

You could try wrapping your custom control in a panel and experiment with anchoring or `Fill`'ing, if it doesn't dock properly to the top.

```
var form = new Form();

var shrinking = new Panel() 
{
    BackColor = Color.Red,
    Dock = DockStyle.Top
};
var filling = new TableLayoutPanel()
{
    BackColor = Color.Green,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill
};

var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = 500;
timer.Tick += (s, a) =>
{
    shrinking.Height -= 10;
    if(shrinking.Height <= 0) {
        shrinking.Height = 0;
        timer.Stop();
    }
};

form.Shown += (s, a) => timer.Start();


// Just to make sure it works with a menu present   
var menu = new MenuStrip();
menu.Items.Add("&File");    

form.Controls.Add(shrinking);   
form.Controls.Add(filling); 
form.Controls.Add(menu);
form.ShowDialog();
```